# How can I add loop in after function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My javascript is like this :

```
$('#thumbnail-view').after(` for(i=0;i<5;i++){ <div>....</div }`);
```

I want to add loop in `after` like that

How can I do it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This doesn't make your intention clear at all.

Comment: why is your loop inside after? i doubt its possible

Comment: I update my question

Comment: I just answered you exactly what you are looking for :) .
I hope thats what you wanted.

Comment: @JaromandaX  "foreign" from what?

Comment: from me @guest271314 :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the string first, before calling the after() function.

For example, this appends the string 123456789 using a loop.

```
var res = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    res += i;
}
$('#thumbnail-view').after(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This how you can achieve what you need exactly.

```
$('#thumbnail-view').after((function(){
        // Here you can write you for loop and return the concatenated string
        var str = ""; 
        for(var i=0; i< 10; i++) {
            str = str + "<div>test</div>";
        }
        return str;
    })());
});
```

It basically creates an IFFE. which executes immediately and returns a string for '$.after()' to consume.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is to create a variable that has all the elements you want. then pass that variable to the after. Do not create a function inside of after. There is no need for it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var divvs = '';
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    divvs+= '<div>hello</div>'
  }
  $('.block').after(divvs);
});
```

Here is the fiddle for reference http://jsbin.com/biluqanupo/edit?html,js,output